# excel stops execution of macros abruptly

Tags: excel, loops, crash, corrupt, vba

I have created a form for a survey and it has over 500 questions which it pulls from a sheet based on condition provided. It also has a combo box which pulls the question number which is alphanumeric. Once the survey starts and finished if there are any questions left unanswered will be displayed in another form and user can go back in the form and answer them. While answering these questions the excel will run through a loop multiple times to validate condition and at a particular question it stops working when it is pulling the question number.
There is no error message, no debugging option the code stops executing without any trace.

```
UserForm1.ComboBox2.Value = QUEST.Range("B" & RQID).Value
```

This is the line in which code stops and then the form disappears as well from the sheet. The RQID value is at most times is 276 and it takes a lot of validation process in loops from 50 to reach this value. Is it because the file is corrupted.

Also, When I double click on the UserForm1 for validation it restarts the excel.

It is occurring in multiple versions of files which used to work fine before. Also I got the first file with problem from my client Is there any way her file could have corrupted my excel application or will this be caused by Add Ins?

Comment: Are there any `End` statements in your code? Or any conditional formatting that uses UDFs?

Comment: No Rory, I don't use any conditional formatting in here neither there are any end statements.

Comment: Pretty hard to comment, I'm afraid as there is clearly nothing inherently wrong with the one line of code you provided.

Comment: Hi Rory,
I know its hard to say anything from the single line of code I provided. 
I don't think its about the code.
Its just that all the lines are executing fine until a particular RQID. Including the mentioned line of code.
Sometimes its 273 or 274 or 276. Are you aware of any scenarios where excel could stop executing the code abruptly in middle of execution without even any error messages?

Comment: Check this - https://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-code-stops-unexpectedly-ghost-break/ It has happened to me quite a lot of times, thus I wrote an article about it! :)

Comment: Hi Vityata,
Thanks for the comment. But my file does not even show the courtesy to show an error message.

Comment: I am - those were the two things that I asked about initially.

Comment: Just tried error handling and the error description was out of stack space.
I googled the reasons and the problem most probably is because of the nested/recursive procedure call.